# java compile error in Netbeans, JCreator, Geany

Tags: java

I'm working on three IDE's. Netbeans, JCreator, Geany. All these three gives the same error message and do not proceed though the source code is perfect.

> javac: file not found: C:\Demo.java Usage: javac

Process completed.

Comment: The error message clearly says that it can't find `c:\Demo.java` are you sure it exists?

Comment: Try and use javac directly in the command line to compile Demo.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Uninstall and re-install Netbeans again.If it says your default installing location is not empty, go there and manually delete existing files of old Netbeans.

Answer (score -1):

try Clean and build and execute again.

Comment: I'd be surprised if a clean/build would help find a missing Java source file. Also, this approach is poorly described considering there are multiple IDEs in use, which presumably have different names for this procedure.